# How to Remove scroller in android?

Tags: android

I am using scroll-view to display the content.
The problem I am facing is I want to removed scroll that display when I scroll down or up of the content .

Comment: One would want to add comment while downvoting. It helps people improve quality of their posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try -

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

Or hide the scrollbars programmatically:

```
view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false); 
view.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove scrollbars set

```
android:scrollbars="none"
```

in the XML of your view.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:scrollbars